# Firestore where clause not returning the same records as when I filter by the same data

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Firebase DB and Chrome debugger]

Looking at the picture on the left I have filtered a collection by an eventName (Spring 2024) and it returns 5 documents. In my code on the right I have used a where clause to retrieve those same 5 records (even hardcoded the Spring 2024) but it is only returning 1 row every time. The (data) variable only contains 1 document. The one it returns is the one 1 entered an hour ago, then I entered 4 more 30 minutes ago using the same software. No matter how many times I restart/rebuild/rerun this call only ever returns that original record even though the Firebase console allows me to see all 5 when I filter it. Any thoughts on how this could be happening? I'm hoping I am making a stupid mistake that you can see quickly. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: That will also give you the chance to ensure the code is a proper minimal repro: as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.